# can't add attachment to calendar event

Tags: office365, office365api

I am trying to add attachment to calendar using Office 365 Starter Project for ASP.NET MVC https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start. As it requires event id I can't add using method AddCalendarEventAsync. So I'm trying to update event using below code:

```
var outlookServicesClient = await AuthenticationHelper.EnsureOutlookServicesClientCreatedAsync("Calendar");
var thisEventFetcher = outlookServicesClient.Me.Calendar.Events.GetById(selectedEventId);
IEvent eventToUpdate = await thisEventFetcher.ExecuteAsync();
```

But 'eventToUpdate' has not Attachment set property. Please could you check this and explain how to add attachment to calendar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var thisEventFetcher = outlookServicesClient.Me.Calendar.Events.GetById(eventID);
Attachment attachment = new FileAttachment
                                {
                                    Name = "test",
                                    ContentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\test.jpeg"),
                                    ContentType = "image/jpeg"
                                };
                                await thisEventFetcher.Attachments.AddAttachmentAsync(attachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested add the attachment to the event with outlookservicesclient, but can't find attachment even the event created successfully .It seems outlookservicesclient not includes the attachment data . If you use Fiddler , you couldn't find the attachment data in post request .

You could try to add attachment to event with Graph API :

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<id>/attachments
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 142

{
   "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
   "name": "name-value",
   "contentBytes": "contentBytes-value"
}
```

Please click [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_post_attachments) for detail information .

Comment: Thanks @nan-yu..I am not able to add attachment using outlookservicesclient. Please could you post code you used for adding attachment to the event with outlookservicesclient would be great. Then I will check first in Fiddler.

Comment: For example ,in AddCalendarEventAsync function in CalendarOperations.cs .after initializing the newEvent ,add the attachment :` FileAttachment ae = new FileAttachment();

                ae.ContentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\f.txt");
                ae.Name = "text";
                ae.Size = Convert.ToInt32(new FileInfo(@"D:\f.txt").Length);
        
                newEvent.Attachments.Add(ae);` Then you could check post request using Fiddler

Comment: please see my answer to this post above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @nan-yu you were right can't find attachment data in n fiddler.  As per documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#Createattachments it requires eventid to save attachment. So I was using code in 'UpdateCalendarEventAsync' method. Just like how attachment works with emails, you save as draft and add attachment to that draft. Below code adds attachment but when I fetch event using eventid the attachment property has no data.

```
Event newEvent = new Event
            {
             Subject = Subject,
                Location = location,
                Attendees = attendees,
                Start = start,
                End = end,
                Body = body
            };

            newEvent.Start = (DateTimeOffset?)CalcNewTime(newEvent.Start, start);
            newEvent.End = (DateTimeOffset?)CalcNewTime(newEvent.End, end);

            try
            {
                // Make sure we have a reference to the Outlook Services client
                var outlookServicesClient = await AuthenticationHelper.EnsureOutlookServicesClientCreatedAsync("Calendar");

                // This results in a call to the service.
                await outlookServicesClient.Me.Events.AddEventAsync(newEvent);
                newEventId = newEvent.Id;
                newEvent.Attachments = attachments;
                newEvent.HasAttachments = true;
                await ((IEventFetcher)newEvent).ExecuteAsync();
                await newEvent.UpdateAsync(true);
                var thisEventFetcher = outlookServicesClient.Me.Calendar.Events.GetById(newEventId);
                IEvent eventToUpdate = await thisEventFetcher.ExecuteAsync();
                await outlookServicesClient.Context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```