# Can not add attachment to an calendar event

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I try to add an attachment to an calendar event using:

```
POST /groups/{id}/calendar/events/{id}/attachments
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
  "name": "menu.txt",
  "contentBytes": "bWFjIGFuZCBjaGVlc2UgdG9kYXk="
}
```

In v1.0 verison I get:

```
Failure - Status Code 403
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "...",
            "date": "2018-03-27T06:50:03"
        }
    }
}
```

However I have all required permissions set.

In beta version I get:

```
Failure - Status Code 400
  {
    "error": {
        "code": "NavigationNotSupported",
        "message": "Recursive navigation is not allowed after property 'Events' according to the entity schema.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "...",
            "date": "2018-03-27T06:59:44"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this just the end point doesn't work or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use the C# code below:

```
var thisEventFetcher = outlookServicesClient.Me.Calendar.Events.GetById(eventID);
Attachment attachment = new FileAttachment{
    Name = "test",
    ContentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\test.jpeg"),
    ContentType = "image/jpeg"
};
await thisEventFetcher.Attachments.AddAttachmentAsync(attachment);
```

**Reference**: [can't add attachment to calendar event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937288/cant-add-attachment-to-calendar-event)

Comment: any chances to do it by rest?